# Programmatically add users in roles in PowerBi Service, when using RLS

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I would like to create a sync job, that takes users from an external system, and creates them as users of a datasource, under a specific role:

[image: Adding users in Roles]

I am struggelig to find a proper API/other way to add users programmatically into these groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time, this is not possible. It is not available as a Power BI REST API, as seen in the [Power BI REST API Datasets reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/rest/api/power-bi/datasets), since RLS is a dataset feature.

A workaround this issue would be to bind an Active Directory group to a RLS role, so you can add programatically users to this AD group and it would be reflected to the Power BI Dataset.

There is an [idea on Power BI Ideas Forum](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/13616925-rest-api-for-managing-roles-of-datasets) that requests this feature, along with the need to create roles within the REST API.